# DynamicSupervisor - problem with communication with the workers

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor, elixir

I have a problem with communication with the workers created in my dynamicSupervisor. after start all my workers i try make a call to one by pid and is generated one error (always). 
At the beginning of the child I keep the pid with ets. Then when I want to make a call to this child I get the pid from the ets by an identifier. So far so good.
The problem is when I do the following:

```
GenServer.call(
  pid,
  {:action_project, %{project_id: project_id, pid: :erlang.pid_to_list(pid)}}
)
```

returns following error:

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.606.0> terminating
** (RuntimeError) attempted to call GenServer #PID<0.606.0> but no handle_call/3 clause was provided
    (backercamp) lib/gen_server.ex:693: MyApplication.ProjectWorker.handle_call/3
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:661: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:690: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message (from #PID<0.680.0>): {:action_project, %{pid: '<0.606.0>', project_id: "23"}}
State: %{pid: '<0.606.0>', project_id: "23"}
Client #PID<0.680.0> is alive

    (stdlib) gen.erl:169: :gen.do_call/4
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:921: GenServer.call/3
```

What's the problem with this call?

DynamicSupervisor code:

```
defmodule MyApplication.Supervisor do
  use DynamicSupervisor

  alias MyApplication.Management

  def start_link(arg) do
    DynamicSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, arg, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(arg) do
    DynamicSupervisor.init(arg)
  end

  def start_project_worker(project_id) do
    spec = {MyApplication.ProjectWorker, %{project_id: project_id}}
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, spec)
  end

  def start_all_project_workers() do
    Enum.each(Management.list_all_projects(), fn %{id: project_id} ->
      IO.puts("Started for project Id [#{project_id}]")
      # 1s between workers
      :timer.sleep(1000)
      start_project_worker("#{project_id}")
    end)
  end

  def action_project(pid, project_id) do
    GenServer.call(
      pid,
      {:action_project, %{project_id: project_id, pid: :erlang.pid_to_list(pid)}}
    )
  end
end
```

Worker code:

```
defmodule MyApplication.ProjectWorker do

  use GenServer, restart: :transient

  alias MyApplication.Settings
  alias MyApplication.Management

  def start_link(state) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state)
  end

  def init(state) do
    schedule_action_project(Settings.get_frequency_ms())
    state = Map.put(state, :pid, :erlang.pid_to_list(self()))
    persist_state(state)
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:schedule_action_project, %{project_id: _project_id, pid: _pid} = state) do
    action_by_state(state)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_call({:action_project}, %{project_id: _project_id, pid: _pid} = state) do
    case action_by_state(state) do
      true ->
        terminate(state)

      false ->
        {:reply, state, state}
    end
  end

  defp persist_state(state) do
    IO.puts(" :: Add project_id [#{state.project_id}] and pid #{state.pid}")
    :ets.insert_new(:project_backup, {state.project_id, state.pid})
  end

  defp delete_persist_state(project_id) do
    IO.puts(" :: Delete project_id [#{project_id}]")
    :ets.delete(:project_backup, project_id)
  end

  defp schedule_action_project(time) do
    IO.puts(" :: Schedule_action_project [#{time}]")
    Process.send_after(self(), :schedule_action_project, time)
  end

  defp terminate(%{project_id: project_id, pid: _pid} = state) do
    IO.puts(
      " :: Stop processed, everything is done! project_id [#{state.project_id}] and pid #{
        state.pid
      }"
    )

    delete_persist_state(project_id)
    {:stop, :normal, state}
  end

  defp action_by_state(%{project_id: _project_id, pid: _pid} = state) do
    action_by_project(Management.get_project!(state.project_id))
  end

  defp action_by_project(%Project{} = project) do
    #do something in project
  end
end
```

Comment: What error do you get? Post the stack trace here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is within a handler. You messed all the arguments up. `state` is an internal state of `GenServer`, you do not pass it through, you receive it in the callback. The following signature will match if your state is a map having keys `project_id` and `pid` and you call it like `GenServer.call(pid, {:action_project})`.

```
def handle_call({:action_project}, %{project_id: _project_id, pid: _pid} = state)
```

You should change this handler to match your caller:

```
def handle_call(
  {:action_project, %{project_id: _project_id, pid: _pid}},
  _from,
  state
)
```

Also note that `handle_call` callback receives *three* parameters (unlike `handle_cast`, the second one being the source of the message.

---

*Sidenote:* `handle_info` callback has the wrong signature as well.

Comment: ohhh you is a machine :D you right in relation to handle_call ... And what is wrong in handle_info?

Comment: The same, I guess. I am not sure what the state is though.

Comment: another doubt. Is it possible to know at the beginning of a child if it comes from a restart? or have different init functions of child?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. If you need a different `init`, the simplest way would be to create another module.

Comment: i want one init for first call and another for restart. it is possible?

Comment: Nope. As a workaround, you might put something like a flag to DETS on the very first start, check this flag from `init` and behave accordingly.